# Askbot Static Files at Webfaction Not Served

Tags: webfaction, askbot

I deployed askbot script on webfaction server by following the instructions at http://community.webfaction.com/questions/8400/need-help-for-askbot-installation. I also have done to run python2.7 manage.py collectstatic and the DEBUG setting are False.

When I visit my website it looks like the following image: http://dl.dropbox.com/u/750152/askbot.png

All the css & image rendering is gone. Am I missing some step ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have not created a Static only app to point to your Static content. 
Static content will be rendered by nginx Front-end Server.

Here are the steps -

```
In the control panel, create a new app
```

i.e as 'Symbolic link to static-only app' using

/home/username/webapps/askbot_server/myask/static as the symlink path.

```
Add the symlink app to your askbot site using '/m' as the URL path.
```

Then,

Edit /home/username/webapps/askbot_server/apache2/conf/httpd.conf to change this to -

```
<Directory /home/username/webapps/askbot_server/htdocs>
    AddHandler wsgi-script .py
</Directory>
to 

WSGIScriptAlias / /home/username/webapps/askbot_server/myask/django.wsgi
Restart your Apache with /home/username/webapps/askbot_server/apache2/bin/restart
```

Also if you are using posgresql as your database, to enable Full Text Search then run

```
python manage.py init_postgresql_full_text_search
```

Comment: yes, I forget add a static app, also I add a trailing slash at the end of /home/username/webapps/askbot_server/myask/static